# ansible community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_get: replaces values with asterisks (*)

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I am using community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_get to read secrets from vault with the below playbook and write the secrets to a file. but instead of writing secrets as is, ansible replaces (test-, test_, *test, -test) with ******* or *****_ like the output below.

the secrets in vault are (just trying different things):

```
env1= test_env1
env2= test_env2
env3= env3-test
```

ansible output in the file:
 `{"env1": "********-env", "env2": "********_env2", "env3": "env3_********"}`

the playbook:

```
    - name: read secrets from vault
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no 
      tasks:
      - name: Read the latest version of a kv2 secret from Vault via the remote host with userpass auth
        community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_get:
          # vault info
          url: http://localhost:8200
          # aut info 
          auth_method: userpass
          mount_point: userpass
          username: "ansible"
          password: "test"
          # secret info
          engine_mount_point: kv
          path: test-dash
        register: mysecret
    
    - name: write sectes to file
      hosts: aws_test
      become: yes
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
      - name: write on aws file
        lineinfile:
          path: /home/ubuntu/mysecret
          create: yes
          line: "{{ item }}"
          state: present
          owner: ubuntu
          group: ubuntu
          mode: "0644"
        with_items:
        - "{{ hostvars['localhost']['mysecret']['secret'] | to_json }}"
```

Comment: What happens if you use a password that isn't `test`?